# Use several selection colors in DT::datatable?

Tags: css, r, shiny, datatables, dt

I have set:

```
output$tableId <- 
   DT::renderDataTable({DT::datatable(..., selection = "multiple")})
```

And I would like the background color of the selection to vary depending on of it's the first selection, or the second, etc.

It should be possible to use `length(input$tableId_rows_selected)` (which is described [here](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html)) to obtain this behaviour? I'm guessing in combination with creating some CSS modifying this:

```
.table.dataTable tbody td.active, .table.dataTable tbody tr.active td {
   background-color: #007bff;
   color: white;
}
```

I know very little CSS, HTML, and JavaScript, so I find these things difficult.

**EDIT 2022-02-14:**

After @StéphaneLaurent initial answer below, I want to change my question slightly:

The logic I would prefer the most is:

1. We have `m` unique colors. `n < m` previous rows have been selected.
2. The `n+1`th row gets selected and is then coloured in the `n+1`th color and keeps this color until deselected.
3. When `m` rows are currently selected, no more selections are possible. Alternatively, I would also be interested in: When the `m+1`th row gets selected, it gets coloured in the first color, and other row occupying this color gets deselected. `m+1` rows are now chosen, and when the `m+2`th row gets selected, it gets coloured in the second color, and the other row occupying this color gets deselected. And so on.

Moreover:

- Since my app will be running through an iframe on a website, and the underlying data of the app will have 10 to 100 million observations, I think a solution where `DT::renderDataTable({...}, server = TRUE)` would be good.
- I also want the solution to work with the `DT::datatable(..., selection = list(mode = "multiple", selected = 1:3, target = "row"))` option.

I will try to implement the above using @StéphaneLaurent answer, combined with the tools @YihuiXie illustrate [here](https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-rows/) (app from page linked earlier).

Answer (score 1):

If you use the following CSS, then the first row will be red if you select it, the second will be green, the third will be blue:

```css
#dtable tbody tr.selected:nth-of-type(1) td {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 9999px red;
}
#dtable tbody tr.selected:nth-of-type(2) td {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 9999px green;
}
#dtable tbody tr.selected:nth-of-type(3) td {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 9999px blue;
}
```

Here `dtable` is the id.

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

css <- "
#dtable tbody tr.selected:nth-of-type(1) td {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 9999px red;
}
#dtable tbody tr.selected:nth-of-type(2) td {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 9999px green;
}
#dtable tbody tr.selected:nth-of-type(3) td {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 9999px blue;
}
"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(
      HTML(css)
    )
  ),
  br(), br(),
  DTOutput("dtable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(iris, selection = "multiple")
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here is how to generate the CSS for 100 rows with a random color, using the **sass** package. Save the following **scss** file, say **mystyle.scss**:

```scss
$s-min: 20;
$s-max: 70;
$l-min: 30;
$l-max: 90;

@for $i from 1 through 100 {
  #dtable tbody tr.selected:nth-of-type(#{$i}) td {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 9999px hsl(random(360),$s-min+random($s-max+-$s-min),$l-min+random($l-max+-$l-min));
  }
}
```

Now compile it to a CSS file:

```r
library(sass)
sass(sass_file("mystyle.scss"), output = "mystyle.css")
```

Put the file **mystyle.css** in the **www** subfolder of the app, and then include it in the app as follows:

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$link(
      href = "mystyle.css", rel = "stylesheet"
    )
  ),
  ......
```

---

## EDIT : jQuery solution

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

js <- '
var colors = ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "purple"];
table.on("select", function(e, dt, type, indexes) {
  var count = table.rows({selected: true}).count();
  for(var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    $("#dtable tbody tr.selected").eq(i).find("td").css(
      "box-shadow", "inset 0 0 0 9999px " + colors[i]
    );
  }
}).on("deselect", function(e, dt, type, indexes) {
  for(var i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
    $("#dtable tbody tr").eq(indexes[i]).find("td").css(
      "box-shadow", ""
    );
  }
  var count = table.rows({selected: true}).count();
  for(var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    $("#dtable tbody tr.selected").eq(i).find("td").css(
      "box-shadow", "inset 0 0 0 9999px " + colors[i]
    );
  }
});
'

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(), br(),
  DTOutput("dtable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      iris, 
      extensions = "Select",
      selection = "none", 
      callback = JS(js),
      options = list(
        "select" = "multi" 
      )
    )
  }, server = FALSE)
  
}
```

---

## EDIT: correction of previous edit

Here is the correct JS code:

```r
js <- '
var colors = ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "purple"];
var stack = [];
table.on("select", function(e, dt, type, indexes) {
  stack.push(indexes[0]);
  for(var i = 0; i < stack.length; i++) {
    $("#dtable tbody tr").eq(stack[i]).find("td").css(
      "box-shadow", "inset 0 0 0 9999px " + colors[i]
    );
  }
}).on("deselect", function(e, dt, type, indexes) {
  var i0 = stack.indexOf(indexes[0]);
  $("#dtable tbody tr").eq(stack[i0]).find("td").css(
    "box-shadow", ""
  );
  stack.splice(i0, 1);
  for(var i = 0; i < stack.length; i++) {
    $("#dtable tbody tr").eq(stack[i]).find("td").css(
      "box-shadow", "inset 0 0 0 9999px " + colors[i]
    );
  }
});
'
```

[image]

---

## EDIT: without the 'Select' extension

```r
js <- '
var colors = ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "purple"];
var stack = [];
table.on("click", "tr", function() {
  var $rows = $("#dtable tbody tr"); // SIMONSIMON I moved this line
  var $row = $(this);
  var idx = $row.index();
  if($row.hasClass("selected")) {
    stack.push(idx);
    for(var i = 0; i < stack.length; i++) {
      $rows.eq(stack[i]).find("td").css(
        "box-shadow", "inset 0 0 0 9999px " + colors[i]
      );
    }
  } else {
    var i0 = stack.indexOf(idx);
    $rows.eq(stack[i0]).find("td").css(
      "box-shadow", ""
    );
    stack.splice(i0, 1);
    for(var i = 0; i < stack.length; i++) {
      $rows.eq(stack[i]).find("td").css(
        "box-shadow", "inset 0 0 0 9999px " + colors[i]
      );
    }
  }
});
'

......

  output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      iris, 
      selection = "multiple", 
      callback = JS(js)
    )
  }, server = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out! However, the code does not do what I want to, maybe my original question was confusing: You always mark the first row as red, the second as green, etc. I want to mark the first clicked selection as red, the second clicked selection as green, etc. Maybe I can modify your code to achieve this.

Comment: @SimonSimon I know, but I didn't find how to do. This is the closest thing I found. Perhaps I have a solution which works only in the Safari browser.

Comment: I'm happy with anything! :) Worst case, perhaps very bad practice but maybe I can update some header with Shiny reactivity or so?

Comment: @SimonSimon I don't know. I'll come back if I have an idea. Please see my edit, using the **sass** package, for fun ;-)

Comment: Thanks, will implement for fun during the afternoon, tried quickly but need to investigate some things! :-) Will also continue trying some ideas about length(input$tableId_rows_selected) to see what sticks.

Comment: @SimonSimon See my latest edit, it works this time!

Comment: I tried the **sass** stuff, for fun, and I've tried your JS code solutions - thank you! However, the current deselect logic is not exactly what I want, but this I should be able to fix myself with your code. More importantly, I will put Shiny on a website using an iframe, with 10+ million rows of data and if I understand things correctly I therefore want to use server-side processing. I have edited my question to reflect these wishes. I will not mark your answer as accepted yet, but if no better answer has arrived in a few days, I will mark yours. Thanks again!

Comment: @SimonSimon No luck :-( Server-side processing is not possible when using the **Select** extension.

Comment: I see what you are saying in the help for `DT::datatable` now: "Note that DT has its own selection implementation and doesn't use the Select extension because the latter doesn't support the server-side processing mode well. Please set this argument to 'none' if you really want to use the Select extension." Do I read this correctly, that there are two different implementations of selection, so `DT::datatable` has its own which is different from [DataTables'](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/)? The way I read this, DT's own implementation seems compatible with server-side processing?

Comment: @SimonSimon But with DT's own implementation, you don't have the `select` and `deselect` events that I use in the callback.

Comment: I see! I'm mostly used to base R and doing some basic plots in ggplot, all of this is kind of above my head. I will modify your scripts to try and get the exact colouring logic I want, will then simply try this live on the website to see how much performance etc is affected!

Comment: @SimonSimon I've finally found a solution without **Select**. See my latest edit.

Comment: I'm sorry: Your two previous JS solutions run and change the colouring selection behaviour, but for the last one I only get the usual blue selection colouring. Maybe I'm doing some mistake on my end..? :/

Comment: @SimonSimon Oh my god you are right: it works with `server=FALSE` only! :-((((

Comment: @SimonSimon I found a solution, see my edit (see **SIMONSIMON I moved this line** in the JS code). BUT I'm sure this will not work if you change the current page. Server-side processing is hell!

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to help out! You are right, it doesn't work after changing page. Just so you know, like I said before: I will let the question be up a few days, and if no better answer comes I will accept yours.

Answer (score 0):

While technically this doesn't do what I originally requested (i.e. changing the selection colouring dynamically), the results from this implementation appear visually similar to the end-user.

The idea behind the solution is to keep track of the row selection counter, update the table via a proxy, and apply conditional formatting.

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(DT)

data(iris)
iris <- suppressWarnings(cbind(as.data.table(iris),
                               currently_selected = numeric(),
                               selected_as_nr     = numeric(),
                               overwrite          = numeric()))

ui <- fluidPage(
  dataTableOutput("table"),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  iris[, currently_selected := 0]
  iris[, selected_as_nr     := NA]
  iris[, overwrite          := 0]
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(iris,
                  selection = list(mode = "multiple",
                                   selected = 1,
                                   target = "row")) %>%
      formatStyle("Sepal.Length",
                  "selected_as_nr",
                  backgroundColor = styleEqual(0:4, c("green",
                                                      "red",
                                                      "black",
                                                      "blue",
                                                      "yellow")))
  })
  
  proxy <- dataTableProxy(outputId = "table")
  
  observeEvent(input$table_rows_selected, {
    
         new_selected_row <- input$table_rows_selected[1]
    iris[new_selected_row, currently_selected := (currently_selected + 1) %% 2]
    
    if (iris[new_selected_row, currently_selected] == 1) {
      
      new_selection_nr <- suppressWarnings(iris[, min(setdiff(0:4, unique(selected_as_nr)))])
      
      if (new_selection_nr != "Inf") {
        
        iris[, overwrite := 0]
        iris[new_selected_row, selected_as_nr := new_selection_nr] 
        
      } else {
        
        overwrite <- iris[, unique(overwrite)]
        
        iris[selected_as_nr == overwrite, currently_selected := 0]
        iris[selected_as_nr == overwrite, selected_as_nr := NA]
        
        iris[new_selected_row, selected_as_nr := overwrite]
        
        iris[, overwrite := (overwrite + 1) %% 5]
      
      }
      
    } else {
      
      iris[new_selected_row, selected_as_nr := NA]
      
    }
    
    DT::replaceData(proxy, iris)
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I cheated slightly and solved another visually similar problem, I wonder what you're opinion is on this solution?

Comment: I welcome other approaches than this though, since it involves a proxy updating the data etc and therefore seems excessively computationally wasteful given the task!